# How to get a bash shell without absolutely anything running silently before or after every command?

Tags: bash

My motivation is to test the `trap '...' DEBUG` and `set -x` commands, but there is just too much noise due to these silently running commands. So how can I run bash without any?

Passing `--noprofile` does not seem to achieve it.

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ bash --noprofile
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ set -x
++ __posh_git_ps1 '\u@\h:\w' '\$ '
++ local ps1pc_prefix=
++ local ps1pc_suffix=
++ case "$#" in
++ ps1pc_prefix='\u@\h:\w'
++ ps1pc_suffix='\$ '
+++ __posh_git_echo
++++ git config --bool bash.enableGitStatus
+++ '[' '' = false ']'
+++ local 'Red=\033[0;31m'
+++ local 'Green=\033[0;32m'
+++ local 'BrightRed=\033[0;91m'
+++ local 'BrightGreen=\033[0;92m'
+++ local 'BrightYellow=\033[0;93m'
+++ local 'BrightCyan=\033[0;96m'
++++ __posh_color '\e[m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\e[m\]'
+++ local 'DefaultForegroundColor=\[\e[m\]'
+++ local DefaultBackgroundColor=
+++ local 'BeforeText=['
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;93m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;93m\]'
+++ local 'BeforeForegroundColor=\[\033[0;93m\]'
+++ local BeforeBackgroundColor=
+++ local 'DelimText= |'
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;93m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;93m\]'
+++ local 'DelimForegroundColor=\[\033[0;93m\]'
+++ local DelimBackgroundColor=
+++ local 'AfterText=]'
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;93m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;93m\]'
+++ local 'AfterForegroundColor=\[\033[0;93m\]'
+++ local AfterBackgroundColor=
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;96m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;96m\]'
+++ local 'BranchForegroundColor=\[\033[0;96m\]'
+++ local BranchBackgroundColor=
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;92m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;92m\]'
+++ local 'BranchAheadForegroundColor=\[\033[0;92m\]'
+++ local BranchAheadBackgroundColor=
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;91m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;91m\]'
+++ local 'BranchBehindForegroundColor=\[\033[0;91m\]'
+++ local BranchBehindBackgroundColor=
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;93m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;93m\]'
+++ local 'BranchBehindAndAheadForegroundColor=\[\033[0;93m\]'
+++ local BranchBehindAndAheadBackgroundColor=
+++ local BeforeIndexText=
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;32m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;32m\]'
+++ local 'BeforeIndexForegroundColor=\[\033[0;32m\]'
+++ local BeforeIndexBackgroundColor=
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;32m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;32m\]'
+++ local 'IndexForegroundColor=\[\033[0;32m\]'
+++ local IndexBackgroundColor=
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;31m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;31m\]'
+++ local 'WorkingForegroundColor=\[\033[0;31m\]'
+++ local WorkingBackgroundColor=
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;91m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;91m\]'
+++ local 'StashForegroundColor=\[\033[0;91m\]'
+++ local StashBackgroundColor=
+++ local 'BeforeStash=('
+++ local 'AfterStash=)'
+++ local LocalDefaultStatusSymbol=
+++ local 'LocalWorkingStatusSymbol= !'
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;31m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;31m\]'
+++ local 'LocalWorkingStatusColor=\[\033[0;31m\]'
+++ local 'LocalStagedStatusSymbol= ~'
++++ __posh_color '\033[0;96m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\033[0;96m\]'
+++ local 'LocalStagedStatusColor=\[\033[0;96m\]'
++++ __posh_color '\e[0m'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
++++ echo '\[\e[0m\]'
+++ local 'RebaseForegroundColor=\[\e[0m\]'
+++ local RebaseBackgroundColor=
++++ git config --get bash.branchBehindAndAheadDisplay
+++ local BranchBehindAndAheadDisplay=
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ BranchBehindAndAheadDisplay=full
++++ git config --bool bash.enableFileStatus
+++ local EnableFileStatus=
+++ case "$EnableFileStatus" in
+++ EnableFileStatus=true
++++ git config --bool bash.showStatusWhenZero
+++ local ShowStatusWhenZero=
+++ case "$ShowStatusWhenZero" in
+++ ShowStatusWhenZero=false
++++ git config --bool bash.enableStashStatus
+++ local EnableStashStatus=
+++ case "$EnableStashStatus" in
+++ EnableStashStatus=true
++++ git config --bool bash.enableStatusSymbol
+++ local EnableStatusSymbol=
+++ case "$EnableStatusSymbol" in
+++ EnableStatusSymbol=true
+++ local BranchIdenticalStatusSymbol=
+++ local BranchAheadStatusSymbol=
+++ local BranchBehindStatusSymbol=
+++ local BranchBehindAndAheadStatusSymbol=
+++ local BranchWarningStatusSymbol=
+++ true
+++ BranchIdenticalStatusSymbol=' ≡'
+++ BranchAheadStatusSymbol=' ↑'
+++ BranchBehindStatusSymbol=' ↓'
+++ BranchBehindAndAheadStatusSymbol=↕
+++ BranchWarningStatusSymbol=' ?'
+++ __POSH_BRANCH_AHEAD_BY=0
+++ __POSH_BRANCH_BEHIND_BY=0
+++ local is_detached=false
++++ __posh_gitdir
++++ '[' -z '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -n '' ']'
++++ '[' -d .git ']'
++++ git rev-parse --git-dir
+++ local g=
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ return
++ local gitstring=
++ PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

I would like to witness empty output when running `set -x` by itself.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`env -i HOME="$HOME" USER="$USER" bash --noprofile --norc` will start you with an empty environment (i.e. without inheriting anything from the parent environment) but explicitly setting `$USER` and `$HOME`. `--norc` and `--noprofile` tell `bash` not to load the startup files.

Alternately, as a quick hack, `env -i bash` will run `bash` with an empty environment — not even `$HOME` or `$USER` — so your `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` etc will not be found, and nothing (except possibly global scripts) will affect your new pristine environment. Obviously, this will not go well if you depend on knowing who you are and where you should be.